# Git repo in Docker image not picking up changes on fresh build

Tags: docker

My Git repo isn't changing in my Docker image even when rebuilding with a new tag.

I run `git clone` in a build and it works:

```
# dockerfile
FROM python:3.8
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# To fix GPG key error when running apt-get update
RUN apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/3bf863cc.pub
RUN apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git

RUN git clone https://github.com/my_git_username/repo_name.git
WORKDIR /repo_name
```

I build:

```bash
docker build -t username/exam:0.1
```

Then, I push a file named `tmp.txt` to that repo, and run a new build:

```bash
docker build -t username/exam:0.2
```

I expect that this command fails, because I changed the repo to private, but it succeeds. So I went inside the container and checked the contents:

```bash
docker run -it username/exam:0.2
```

```py
import os
print(os.listdir(os.getcwd()))
```

And I confirm that `tmp.txt` does not exist (which is the previous state of the repo).

This is what I would expect:

```
=> ERROR [6/7] RUN git clone https://github.com/my_git_username/repo_name.git                                                                                                                 1.1s 
------
>  > [6/7] RUN git clone https://github.com/my_git_username/repo_name.git:
> #10 0.632 Cloning into 'repo_name'...
> #10 1.007 fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
> ------
> executor failed running [/bin/sh -c git clone https://github.com/my_git_username/repo_name.git]: exit code: 128
```

What I need help with:

- Why is the git repo at the previous commit in the second image?
- How can I automatically bring the latest modifications without modifying the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 6):

Use `docker build --no-cache`. Docker [caches layers](https://docs.docker.com/build/cache/), and is likely caching the `git clone` layer (step), because the command hasn't changed and the checksums of the previous layers haven't changed.

Example: `docker build --no-cache -t username/exam:0.3 .`.